# Triangle of numbers with recursion

Tags: java, recursion, numbers

So I have to make a program that prints out a triangle of numbers in a sense that if, let's say, the input is `triangleOfNumbers(1, 5)` it prints out:

```
1
1 2
1 2 3
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 5
```

I quickly figured how to do it with loops:

```
    for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
        for (int j = start; j <= i; j++) {
            System.out.print(j + " ");
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
```

But as much as I hit my head against the wall I just can't figure out how to do it with recursion. I'm actually starting to think that I'm no good for programming if I can't figure such a simple thing out.

Anyways.. any solution or tip would be appreciated! If you'd want to get more into details and actually explain what's going on in said recursion it would be even better!

Answer (score 2):

The first function recursively fills a row. Starting at a number the function keeps concatenating numbers as strings until one is reached and the recursion stops. The second function does the same thing except concatenating rows until the lower bound reaches the upper bound.

```
public class Test 
{

    public static String row(int n) 
    {
        if (n == 1)
            return "1";

        else 
            return row(n - 1) + " " + n;
    }

    public static String triangle(int a, int b)
    {
        if (a == b)
            return row(b);

        else
            return row(a) + "\n" + triangle(a + 1, b);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println(triangle(1, 10));
    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry.. Apparently I lied. I should have both start and end as arguments in the function. Edited my question appropriately.

Comment: Okay, fixed it. You need two recursive functions. One to create the row recursively and one to create the triangle by concatenating rows with newlines.

Comment: So it can't happen with one function alone, can it? A `void` one probably? Anyways.. Thanks! A lot! Gotta read it like a dozen times before it sinks in though.

Comment: No, why? It's the only way, could you please mark as answer?

Comment: Do you understand the row function at the very least?

Comment: Oh, yeah, sure. Was just about to do so anyways. :)

Comment: So let's say we pass in 5. The row function will concatenate 5, 4, 3, 2, and finally 1 with a space between each. This is row five built recursively.

Comment: Next is the triangle function. We pass in 1 and 10, concatenating row 1, 2, 3, until row 10 is reached all with newlines between them all.

Comment: Yes, I kind of got it, thank you! The whole concept of the function returning a value backwards after it's done is kind of odd to me so I guess that's my biggest problem with recursion. I hope I get used to it sooner than later, though.

Comment: I found a little problem though. If my start is > 1 it's not a triangle anymore. With `start = 2` the first line of the triangle should be a single `2` instead of `1 2`. Trying to modify it a bit currently but I guess I'll have to combine the two functions somehow in order to do so. Or at least add a second argument to the `row` one?

Comment: What is your expected output if the start is two? I thought that this is what you wanted. Do you wish to ignore the first argument and start at one regardless?

Comment: e.g.: start = 2 & end = 5 ... should output to `First row` - `2`, `Second row` - `2 3`, `Third row` - `2 3 4`, `Fourth row` - `2 3 4 5`.. It should basically remain a triangle (hence the title) with one single element (the start one) up on top.

Comment: Oh, okay, I fix it up.

Answer (score 0):

This code help you to print such pattern.

```
public String triangle(int n){
    if(n<=0){
        return "";
    }else{
    String p=triangle(n-1);
    p=p +""+ (n);
    System.out.println(p);
    return p;
    }
}
```